# Override Magento Controller without using require_once or include_once

Tags: magento

Is there any way to override Magento controller without using require_once or include_once ?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You'd at least need to change the Magento Autoloader to achieve this, since Magento controller file names use a different (Zend) naming scheme than autoloaded classes (slashes vs. underscores). But I'd **not** recommend to so, because autoloading controllers would take the Magentos standard routing/dispatching processes completely out of control.